# Re define cd to "cd <directory> ls -F" problems

Tags: function, user-input, ls, cd

In my .bash_profile, I have

```
cd(){ builtin cd $1 ls -F }
```

To change cd to cd ls -F. This seems to work for the most part, but when I want to cd to a multi-word directory, it doesn't work. It thinks that the two words are two separate inputs. To try fixing this, I also tried:

```
cd "word1 word2"
cd "word1\ word2"

dir=$"word1 word2"
cd "$dir"
```

and none of these have worked. Do I need to modify my cd function? Or am I just overlooking a clever input method?

Comment: [Quote the variable!](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, It's still doing the same thing:

`dir=$"word1 word2"
cd "$dir"`

Returns:

`bash: cd: word1: No such file or directory`

Comment: You also need either a semicolon or a newline between `cd "$1"` and `ls -F`... Trying to `cd "some where else" ls -F` doesn't really make sense, as `cd` takes only a single argument.

Comment: @gdavtor Remove that `$`. `dir="word1 word2"`, `cd "$dir"` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what (I think) you want:

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "${1-$(echo ~)}" && ls -F
}
```

Note a few things:

- The variable is quoted, so that `cd 'some dir with spaces'` will work.
- There's a `&&` between `cd` and `ls`, so that the latter will not happen if the former fails. (They could just be on different lines, but then `ls` will be run even if `cd` fails, and `cd`'s message about failing will be ‘lost’ among `ls`'s output. (Not sure how just having the commands on the same line was supposed to work.))
- `$1` defaults to `~` so that just `cd` works as expected.